# Running a .sh file on windows to recover single table from Mysql .sql file

Tags: mysql, sh

I have a backup of of mysql database and i just need 1 table from it in a hurry.

Its 4gb and ive tried trying to open it with programs like VIM and it didnt go well, guess its too big. Even doing that trying to extract one table from so much text would be difficult.

So i came across this:
http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mydumpsplitter-extract-tables-from-mysql-dump-shell-script

Which explains how to do it with a shell script. And i found out with http://cygwin.com you can run shell scripts in windows, im running windows 8.1.

Im not really clear what the steps are:

So i run cwygin and get into the shell script window
i put my database file and the mysqldumpsplitter.sh in the C:\cygwin64\usr\mysql folder i created.

Then i go to the /usr/mysql and i run this:

```
sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh mydatabase.sql tbl_activity
```

tbl_activity is the table im trying to access. and mydatabase.sql is the sql backup

but when i run that i get

mysqldumpsplitter.sh: line 5: tput: command not found
mysqldumpsplitter.sh: line 6: tput: command not found
mysqldumpsplitter.sh: line 7: tput: command not found
mysqldumpsplitter.sh: line 8: tput: command not found
mysqldumpsplitter.sh: line 9: tput: command not found
mysqldumpsplitter.sh: line 10: tput: command not found
mysqldumpsplitter.sh: line 11: tput: command not found
mysqldumpsplitter.sh: line 12: tput: command not found
mysqldumpsplitter.sh: line 13: tput: command not found
mysqldumpsplitter.sh: line 14: tput: command not found
0 Table extracted from mydatabase.sql at .

Line 5=14 is below

```
txtund=$(tput sgr 0 1)    # Underline
txtbld=$(tput bold)       # Bold
txtred=$(tput setaf 1)    # Red
txtgrn=$(tput setaf 2)    # Green
txtylw=$(tput setaf 3)    # Yellow
txtblu=$(tput setaf 4)    # Blue
txtpur=$(tput setaf 5)    # Purple
txtcyn=$(tput setaf 6)    # Cyan
txtwht=$(tput setaf 7)    # White
txtrst=$(tput sgr0)       # Text reset
```

While i could potentially get access to a ubuntu machine and run this (i assume this will work better there) i would have to wait hours for the 4gb .sql dump to upload and im hoping to do this quickly. Is it simply a hack running this on windows and i should switch to ubuntu to run it instead?

Full .sh file here since its small

```
#!/bin/sh
# http://kedar.nitty-witty.com
#SPLIT DUMP FILE INTO INDIVIDUAL TABLE DUMPS
# Text color variables
txtund=$(tput sgr 0 1)    # Underline
txtbld=$(tput bold)       # Bold
txtred=$(tput setaf 1)    # Red
txtgrn=$(tput setaf 2)    # Green
txtylw=$(tput setaf 3)    # Yellow
txtblu=$(tput setaf 4)    # Blue
txtpur=$(tput setaf 5)    # Purple
txtcyn=$(tput setaf 6)    # Cyan
txtwht=$(tput setaf 7)    # White
txtrst=$(tput sgr0)       # Text reset

TARGET_DIR="."
DUMP_FILE=$1
TABLE_COUNT=0

if [ $# = 0 ]; then
        echo "${txtbld}${txtred}Usage: sh MyDumpSplitter.sh DUMP-FILE-NAME${txtrst} -- Extract all tables as a separate file from dump."
        echo "${txtbld}${txtred}       sh MyDumpSplitter.sh DUMP-FILE-NAME TABLE-NAME ${txtrst} -- Extract single table from dump."
        echo "${txtbld}${txtred}       sh MyDumpSplitter.sh DUMP-FILE-NAME -S TABLE-NAME-REGEXP ${txtrst} -- Extract tables from dump for specified regular expression."
        exit;
elif [ $# = 1 ]; then
        #Loop for each tablename found in provided dumpfile
        for tablename in $(grep "Table structure for table " $1 | awk -F"\`" {'print $2'})
        do
                #Extract table specific dump to tablename.sql
                sed -n "/^-- Table structure for table \`$tablename\`/,/^-- Table structure for table/p" $1 > $TARGET_DIR/$tablename.sql
                TABLE_COUNT=$((TABLE_COUNT+1))
        done;
elif [ $# = 2  ]; then
        for tablename in $(grep -E "Table structure for table \`$2\`" $1| awk -F"\`" {'print $2'})
        do
                echo "Extracting $tablename..."
                #Extract table specific dump to tablename.sql
                sed -n "/^-- Table structure for table \`$tablename\`/,/^-- Table structure for table/p" $1 > $TARGET_DIR/$tablename.sql
                TABLE_COUNT=$((TABLE_COUNT+1))
        done;
elif [ $# = 3  ]; then

        if [ $2 = "-S" ]; then
                for tablename in $(grep -E "Table structure for table \`$3" $1| awk -F"\`" {'print $2'})
                do
                        echo "Extracting $tablename..."
                        #Extract table specific dump to tablename.sql
                        sed -n "/^-- Table structure for table \`$tablename\`/,/^-- Table structure for table/p" $1 > $TARGET_DIR/$tablename.sql
                        TABLE_COUNT=$((TABLE_COUNT+1))
                done;
        else
                echo "${txtbld}${txtred} Please provide proper parameters. ${txtrst}";
        fi
fi

#Summary
echo "${txtbld}$TABLE_COUNT Table extracted from $DUMP_FILE at $TARGET_DIR${txtrst}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the program UltraEdit: it opens files without buffering the entire content. You can use the evaluation version for 30 days I believe.

Strangely enough, this is the only program (Windows/Linux) I know of which does not buffer an entire file. It has helped me on many occasions.

Answer (score 0):

I would not go that long way. I would just use what I have at hand. I guess, you know the table structure and need the data only. So I would use something like the following in `cmd`:

```
C:\tmp>findstr "^INSERT INTO your_table" < mydatabase.sql > filtered.sql
```

To be sure, how the INSERT statements look like in file you might run something like:

```
C:\tmp>findstr "INSERT INTO" < mydatabase.sql | more
```

And then exit by `Ctrl+C`.